# Equation for Circle in 3D Space Given Center, Radius, and Point

Tags: circles, 3d

I'm looking for how to derive the equation of a circle, in 3D space, given the following information:

- The Center Point
- The Radius
- One point on the circle

I understand that this is functionally the intersection of a plane (x+y+z=d) and a sphere (x^2+y^2+z^2=r), but I'm at a loss how to combine those into a single equation for graphing purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: Knowing the center and just one point does not fix the circle. For example, if the center is at the origin and the point is on the $x$-axis, you don't know if the circle lies on the $xy$-plane, or the $xz$-plane, or anywhere in between. If you knew *two* points then you could get somewhere.